# What to do when a user directly and negatively calls another user's answer?

Tags: discussion, flags, etiquette

I was recently reviewing in the "Late Post" review queue and came across this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37665641/4221083

I commented on the question that the user should have provided some commentary and that a link by itself is not a sufficient answer.

But in the answer the user directly and negatively calls out another user's answer:

> "and the reason why I think Kunta Kinte's solution doesn't work"

I feel like that isn't good practice in this community. If I didn't agree with another answer I would just post my own answer and expect the OP to decipher between was it right or wrong when they apply the answers into their own work.

Should I flag it as offensive or rude?

Comment: Well, it's definitely a link-only answer. It's not _offensive_ by any means, but it's more a comment than an answer and should either be edited or deleted. (Though if the answer they link to answers the question, the question should likely be closed as a duplicate.)

Comment: It's perfectly reasonable to refer to other users' posts in my view, as long as you focus on the content (this code doesn't work) rather than the author (this person is stupid). The example you've given is bad for other reasons, don't conflate the two issues.

Comment: How is that offensive? It is directed at the post, not the user. Stating that a solution doesn't work is constructive _and_ helpful to everyone (saying _why_ would be even better).

Comment: If it had more actual content explaining _why_ another answer is wrong, that would be more productive.  But as it is, that aspect of the answer isn't offensive or in need of editing.  There are other issues with the answer, but "calling out another answer" isn't one of them.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, that is why I asked before taking any actions.

Comment: Keep in mind there's also there's a significant penalty for a validated rude/offensive flag. [6 flags (spam or offensive): post is locked, deleted, and the first revision owner loses 100 reputation.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/305827) (Plus an implicit downvote)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's set aside the merits of the specific answer you refer to, for a moment to address the general principles.

Explaining in an answer why another answer does not work, or is a bad practice does not *by itself* warrant flagging the answer as rude or offensive. It can be **extremely useful** to specifically call out another answer which *looks* to novice eyes like it would work, but is clearly problematic to expert eyes. As long as the explanation remains directed at the other answer, and not at the user, if the author of the called-out answer feels hurt merely because someone else pointed out a problem in it, too bad.

If you find that the answer is not useful *overall*, you *can* downvote. Your decision can be based on whether the argument regarding the other answer is convincing. If the answer calling out the other one is really a comment on another answer you can flag as NAA (not an answer).

The example you gave us is a case of a link-only answer. You can flag it as NAA. Flagging for rudeness or offensiveness is not okay.

Comment: Thanks for the input, trying to continue to learn how to better participate in the community. Glad I posted the question.

Comment: Where something starts becoming rude or offensive is when the criticism is targeted at an individual or group instead of the content itself. Saying "this answer is wrong because" is acceptable, saying "this answerer is an idiot because" is not.

Answer (score 2):

Given how many poor answers are out there, I think it's extremely helpful to point out the flaws in the other answers and how/why your code is better.

One of the major problems I see with answers is that I am not convinced that they are even good. Sure they may seem to work, but how well does it perform under other cases?

Indeed, I explain why my answer is better than existing answers. Just today I wrote this answer:

> The other answer breaks if there are more than just one set of brackets. I would use this instead:
>
> ```
> <[^>]+>
> ```
>
> Essentially, the char class ensures that the match does not catch an ending `>`.
>
> ...

Of course, answers must still stand on their own. I can't see the linked answer as it appears to be gone, but link-only answers should be deleted no matter if they criticize others or not.